# Why MQTT client cannot reconnect?

Tags: android, mqtt

I am writing a MQTT client for Android. I am using ia92 library (wmqtt.jar) and trying to get messages from MQ in order to show them as android notifications. My problem is that the first time I try to connect to the MQ, my android client app successfully connects and MQ messages can be taken normally. When I switch Wi-Fi off and break the network connection, MQTT client connection drops as expected, but when I switch it on again, the app does not establish the MQ connection and throws a MQTTException, that has no error code.

```
mqttClient.connect(this.mqttClientId, cleanStart, keepAliveSeconds);
```

What can be wrong with this? I heavily need any little bit of help..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd be better off using the Paho Java client as ia92 is no longer developed nor supported. http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/

Comment: @ralight can you please suggest me any sample concerning paho use in Android?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but try https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app/src/org/eclipse/paho/sample/mqttv3app/Sample.java

Answer (score 2):

The Java Paho Client implementation contains an Android Service Client and sample:
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/tree/master/org.eclipse.paho.android.service

You can also find an example of using Java Paho Client for implementing Push notifications in Android:
https://github.com/dobermai/android-mqtt-push

Comment: I don't see any automatic reconnection mechanism in the link of the second example. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Your **callback** has to listen to **connectionLost** then do a **client.connect()**

See this example of [callback connectionLost implementation] (
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/496f94a58a41557ba2401d4ba94bc099a75ba8ef/org.eclipse.paho.jmeclient/org.eclipse.paho.jmeclient.mqttv3.MIDPSample/src/org/eclipse/paho/jmeclient/mqttv3/sampleMIDP/WmqttMgr.java)